# Как настроить установку через Visual Studio Installer проект?

Tags: visual-studio, setup

Имеется приложение, которое устанавливаете с помощью Visual Studio Installer Project. Мне необходимо так же регистрировать в реестре свой URL протокол. Как писать в реестр я нашел, но мне нужно в реестре установить для одного из ключей путь к приложению, а для этого надо знать куда пользователь это приложение устанавливает. 
Видел в свойствах такие вещи: [Manufacturer], [ProgramFilesFolder], [ProductName]. Есть ли что-то такое для получения пути установки?

Comment: Используйте Installer class, через него можно творить чудеса :) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer?view=netframework-4.7.2 , https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-installer-classes-to-ease-deployment-in-vs-net/ , https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/ , http://devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=339

Comment: @NewView Спасибо, но хотелось бы сделать по-проще обычным визардом. 
Вот это случаем не то что мне надо?  https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/msi/targetdir

Comment: Создать сателитную сборку это же очень быстро, и открываются масса возможностей. Сам по себе инсталлятор довольно "деревянный" по возможностям, это обусловлено временем его существования и обратной совместимостью. Рекомендую построить сателитную сборку на основе Install класса (dll), а не искать костыли, они там не предусмотренны другим образом :)

Comment: @NewView Деревянность и обратная совместимость в моей задаче как раз таки не лишняя) Сделал вроде. Создал в проекте класс-наследник Installer и переопределил методы OnAfterInstall и OnBeforeUninstall. А в самом проекте инталлера указал настраиваемые действия для целевого проекта. 

Класс Installer содержит поле Context, а в нем словарь  Parameters, содержащий assemblypath.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вроде.

Создал в проекте класс-наследник Installer и переопределил методы OnAfterInstall и OnBeforeUninstall.

А в самом проекте инталлера указал настраиваемые действия для целевого проекта. Класс Installer содержит поле Context, а в нем словарь Parameters, содержащий assemblypath.

Класс-наследник:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class AutoRunInstaller : Installer
{
    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        // ткрываем нужную ветку в реестре   
        // @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\"  

        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Key =
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);



        Key.SetValue("TicketPrinter", base.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);
        Key.Close();

        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

        var pci = new ProcessStartInfo(base.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]);

        Process.Start(pci);

    }

    protected override void OnAfterUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\TicketPrinter", false);

        base.OnAfterUninstall(savedState);
    }
}
```

Его не требуется где-либо вызывать, он просто должен быть вместе с основным проектом. Нужно лишь указать в проекте инсталлера во View-> CustomActions для нужного события Основные выходные файлы нужного проекта. 
Прикладываю скрин:
[image: CustomActions]

Comment: Одно НО, указывать CustomAction надо везде, даже если у вас там нет собственного кода и логики. Просто оставьте пустые функции для Commit, Rollback, Uninstall в том числе и пропишите их в CustomAction. Иначе сломается на этих операциях.

Comment: И в CustomAction не надо засовывать основные выходные файлы.

Comment: @NewView Извините, но не понял вас. Вы говорите прописать в CustomActions, но не сувать в них основные выходные файлы. Это как? 
Да и не крешится ничего при установке, все в порядке.

Comment: @NewView возможно у нас разные подходы. Я не заменяю основной Installer, а лишь наследуюсь от него и переопределяю нужные мне методы. Остальная часть инсталлера работает как штатном режиме.

Comment: Дело не в этом, там единственная логика наследования - другого не дано. Но легче попробовать, увидите когда сломается. :)

Comment: Вот так это например выглядит у меня https://imgur.com/a/Z5udCM7

Comment: Вот так выглядит у меня. Проблем при установке не было.
https://imgur.com/a/f8nNs3V